# R Making Tree Plot with Gradient-Colored Boxes

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame, ex, that has different combinations of letters and counts associated with each combination. I want to create a tree plot that has rectangles surrounding each combination, with the combination with most letters at top and then nodes below with groupings of other combinations. I want to shade the color of each box on a gradient, with one color indicating a higher count and another color indicating a lower count. Ideally, this tree should also look quite simple, with invisible branches and the only text being the combinations and a legend for the color gradient, which could also be made separately. I have tried using rpart, but this seems to be for discrete value only. Is there any way I can create this tree on R?

ex:

```
  letters counts
1       a      2
2      ab      5
3       d      6
4      be      3
5     ade     10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `rpart` to do that-- it can handle a continuous outcome. Combine it with `fancyRpartPlot` to do the visualization of the tree and you can get a gradient color in the final leaves of the tree. See my example, where college GPA was the continuous outcome variable. This was done with the `rpart` and then plotted with `fancyRpartPlot`.

[image: fancyRpartPlot example]

Comment: However, I want to make the tree plot so that there are no edges for each node and no filtering criteria along the edges visible, as well as a gradient for all boxes

Comment: I understand. You'll need to go read through the `fancyRpartPlot` documentation-- there are literally hundreds of options. There's a general layout option with 5 or 6 choices. Start with that and see which one is closest, then you can tweak it further. `rattle` also has some other methods for plotting `rpart` trees.